# In SQL I want to display the names of all those cities which end with an vowel

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote the following query

```
SELECT UNIQUE 
    CITY 
FROM 
    STATION 
WHERE 
    (CITY LIKE '%A' OR 
     CITY LIKE '%E' OR 
     CITY LIKE '%I' OR 
     CITY LIKE '%O' OR 
     CITY LIKE '%U') 
ORDER BY 
    CITY;
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it to work with lower/upper letters, you could use `UPPER(CITY)`, otherwise it's all good.

Answer (score 9):

I think you can use `REGEXP_LIKE` like this:

```
SELECT UNIQUE CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CITY, '[AaEeIiOoUu]$') 
ORDER BY CITY;
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me (Oracle 11g):

```
select distinct
    s.city
from
    station s
where 
    upper(substr(s.city,-1,1)) in ('A','E','I','O','U');
```

Answer (score 2):

We can supply another parameter to `regexp` to handle case sensitivity:

- `i` - case insensitive,
- `c` - case sensitive

For example:

```
select distinct city 
from station 
where regexp_like(city,'[aeiou]$','i')
order by city
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that it will be easier to do it this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION  
WHERE CITY LIKE '%[AaEeIiOoUu]'*
```

Answer (score 1):

Use upper function.This function will help you to capitalize the letter of your text.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM   STATION 
WHERE  UPPER(CITY) LIKE '%A' 
   OR  UPPER(CITY) LIKE '%E' 
   OR  UPPER(CITY) LIKE '%I' 
   OR  UPPER(CITY) LIKE '%O' 
   OR  UPPER(CITY) LIKE '%U';
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Below solution works for Oracle DB:

```
select distinct(city) 
from station 
where UPPER(substr(city,1,1)) 
in ('A','E','I','O','U');
```

If you do not use **UPPER**, then your test cases in which city name is starting with lower case letter will fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   Distinct(CITY)
FROM
   STATION
WHERE
   UPPER(SUBSTR(CITY,1,1)) IN ('A','E','I','O','U');
```

It is working in MySQL.

Comment: Hi, to make your answer more readable you could wrap it in a codeblock by using [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UNIQUE CITY FROM STATION 
WHERE 
    (CITY LIKE 'A%' OR 
     CITY LIKE 'E%' OR
     CITY LIKE 'I%' OR 
     CITY LIKE 'O%' OR 
     CITY LIKE 'U%');
```

% wild card character should come after the alphabet

Answer (score 0):

In MySql

```
    select distinct city 
    from Station 
    where ( city regexp '.[aeiou]$' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code for your purpose!!

```
select distinct CITY from STATION 
where ( CITY like '%a' or 
        CITY like '%e' or 
        CITY like '%i' or 
        CITY like '%o' or 
        CITY like '%u')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY LIKE '%A' 
   OR CITY LIKE '%E' 
   OR CITY LIKE '%I' 
   OR CITY LIKE '%O' 
   OR CITY LIKE '%U';
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is using regular expression:

```
SELECT 
  CITY 
FROM 
  STATION 
WHERE 
  CITY RLIKE "[aeiouAEIOU]$";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM city WHERE LOWER(name) RLIKE '.*[aeiou]$'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UNIQUE CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE UPPER(SUBSTR(CITY,LENGTH(CITY),1)) IN ('A','E','I','O','U');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In SQL Server this could be other version of the answer

```
select distinct city 
from station 
where right(city,1) in ('a','e','i','o','u')
```

Answer (score -1):

**For Oracle**

```
select DISTINCT(CITY) from STATION where upper(SUBSTR(CITY,-1,1)) IN ('A','I','O','E','U');
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using MySQL try this solution:

```
SELECT UNIQUE CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE (CITY REGEXP '%A$' OR CITY REGEXP '%E$' OR CITY REGEXP '%I$' OR CITY REGEXP '%O$' OR CITY REGEXP '%U$') 
ORDER BY CITY;
```